# running java program in a php script

Tags: php

i want to run a java code after the php script takes a input from the browser and then pass on the answer back on the server
can someone help me with this

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP's [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function.

Example:

```
$result = exec("java -jar yourjava.jar");
```

Java program's last standard output line will be stored in `$result`.

If you need capturing standard output:

```
$out = array();
exec = ("java -jar yourjava.jar", $out);
print_r($out);
```

Comment: Actually, according to the documentation the return value is the last line that the program outputted, not the exit status. If I am not mistaken, if you need to get the exit status you should provide a variable that it will go into as the third parameter.

Comment: @EdoDodo: awesome. Will fix that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want something like this:

```
exec("/path/to/program $argumentToPass");
```

Comment: i also wanted to have inputs send to my program how could i do that

Comment: In my code example, the variable $argumentToPass will be sent to the program as its only argument. If you explain in more detail the inputs you want to pass, I can give you a better example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this](http://php.net/manual/de/book.java.php) is what you're looking for (the question is very unspecific) - otherwise, if you just want to execute something (regardless of wether it's a java-programm or something else) use [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.exec.php) like the others said.

Comment: thanks for the hint KingCrunch. it's not said wich php-version is used (and unfortunately there are still a lot of people out there using php4) - and on the liked site, there's a commet with some solutions for php5.